# Get POST params in Laravel's Controller (sent by javascript/vue)

Tags: javascript, laravel, vue.js

I'm sending Form data from a Vue component to Laravel API by POST method.

Laravel return a good response but I'm not able to manage the POST data inside the Laravel controller.

This is the client side:

```
 let body = JSON.stringify({
      'email': user.email,
      'password': user.password,
  });

  fetch("/login", {
         method: "POST",
         headers: new Headers({
            'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
            'X-CSRF-TOKEN': user.token, // NOTA: no X_CXRF-TOKEN
             body: body
                })
   })
```

This is the controller

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers\Auth;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;

class LoginJWTController extends Controller{
  public function login(Request $request){
    print_r ($request->all());
  }
}
```

But the response (**200 OK**) is an empty array: array[]

On debug site I see the request header having:

> body: {"email":"me@xxxxx.xx","password":"12345678"}

Why I have no POST data in my Controller? What I'm missing?

Thanks for your help!

Comment: change this `'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'` to 'Content-`Type': 'application/json'` and one more thing why are sending your body in headers .

Comment: Content-type it's ok, the body it's the issue! I wrote it in a bad position! lol!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Currently the body is part of your headers.

Please try this:

```
let body = JSON.stringify({
    'email': user.email,
    'password': user.password,
});
```

```
fetch("/login", {
     method: "POST",
     headers: new Headers({
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        'X-CSRF-TOKEN': user.token, // NOTA: no X_CXRF-TOKEN
     }),
     body: body
})
```

Also set the content type to `application/json` as Salman Zafar pointed out in the comments.

Comment: Yes! This is! I wrote it too quickly!!  Fresh eyes are always welcome! Thanks for your time and caught the bug! :D